# data-mage-init breaks in cms static blocks - how do i get tabs?

Tags: magento2, tabs, cms-block, data-mage-init

I need a block with tab content, so a client can edit categories when needed. I have been using mage-init but it breaks if you try to edit after the first save.

It's these two lines below. Once edited the mage-init code gets stripped out.

```
<div class="tabs-list bestseller-product tabs-list-sty03" data-mage-init="{"tabs":{"openedState":"active"}}">
```

Full code below

```
<div class="cdz-product-tabs product-style20">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-24">
<div class="cdz-block-title">
<p class="b-title h2" style="color: #139140;">Featured Test Products</p>
</div>
<div class="tabs-list bestseller-product tabs-list-sty03" data-mage-init="{"tabs":{"openedState":"active"}}">
<ul class="nav nav-tabs hidden-xs abs-dropdown" data-mage-init="{"Codazon_ProductFilter/js/productfilter":{"codazon.mobiledropdown":{}}}">


<li class="data item title text-uppercase" data-role="collapsible"><a class="data switch" tabindex="0" href="#best-seller-tab-1" data-toggle="switch">Decking &amp; Fencing</a></li>
<li class="data item title text-uppercase" data-role="collapsible"><a class="data switch" tabindex="0" href="#best-seller-tab-2" data-toggle="switch">Flooring</a></li>
<li class="data item title text-uppercase" data-role="collapsible"><a class="data switch" tabindex="0" href="#best-seller-tab-3" data-toggle="switch">Gardens</a></li>
</ul>
<div class="tab-content product data items">
<div id="best-seller-tab-1" class="data item content" data-role="content">{{widget type="Codazon\ProductFilter\Block\Product\ProductsList" display_type="all_products" products_count="16" order_by="entity_id ASC" show="thumb,name,review,price,addtocart,addto" thumb_width="300" thumb_height="300" filter_template="custom" custom_template="grid_slider.phtml" show_slider="1" slider_item="4" conditions_encoded="^[`1`:^[`type`:`Magento||CatalogWidget||Model||Rule||Condition||Combine`,`aggregator`:`all`,`value`:`1`,`new_child`:``^],`1--1`:^[`type`:`Magento||CatalogWidget||Model||Rule||Condition||Product`,`attribute`:`category_ids`,`operator`:`==`,`value`:`5, 6`^]^]"}}</div>
<div id="best-seller-tab-2" class="data item content" data-role="content">{{widget type="Codazon\ProductFilter\Block\Product\ProductsList" display_type="all_products" products_count="6" order_by="price ASC" show="thumb,name,review,price,addtocart,addto" thumb_width="300" thumb_height="300" filter_template="custom" custom_template="grid_slider.phtml" show_slider="1" slider_item="4" conditions_encoded="^[`1`:^[`type`:`Magento||CatalogWidget||Model||Rule||Condition||Combine`,`aggregator`:`all`,`value`:`1`,`new_child`:``^],`1--1`:^[`type`:`Magento||CatalogWidget||Model||Rule||Condition||Product`,`attribute`:`category_ids`,`operator`:`==`,`value`:`8`^]^]"}}</div>
<div id="best-seller-tab-3" class="data item content" data-role="content">{{widget type="Codazon\ProductFilter\Block\Product\ProductsList" display_type="all_products" products_count="14" order_by="entity_id DESC" show="thumb,name,review,price,addtocart,addto" thumb_width="300" thumb_height="300" filter_template="custom" custom_template="grid_slider.phtml" show_slider="1" slider_item="4" conditions_encoded="^[`1`:^[`type`:`Magento||CatalogWidget||Model||Rule||Condition||Combine`,`aggregator`:`all`,`value`:`1`,`new_child`:``^],`1--1`:^[`type`:`Magento||CatalogWidget||Model||Rule||Condition||Product`,`attribute`:`category_ids`,`operator`:`==`,`value`:`9`^]^]"}}</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated